# How to return multiple variables from a function in a controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to return two variables from my controller function. The purpose of this is to use them both in my index.blade.php form.

```
public function index()

    {
        $checkauth=Auth::check();
        $postl= PostModell::orderby('created_at','desc')->paginate(4);

        return view ('posts.index')->with('postl',$postl);
    }
```

From the above sample code the two variables are `$checkauth` and `$postl`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
return view ('posts.index', compact('postl', 'checkauth'));
```

Or:

```
return view ('posts.index', ['postl' => $postl, 'checkauth' => $checkauth]);
```

But actually you don't need to pass `$checkauth` because you can do the check in the view directly with:

```
@if (auth()->check())
```

Or even with the [`@auth`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#control-structures) directive:

```
@auth
    {{-- The user is authenticated --}}
@endauth
```

Comment: if ( auth()->check())
Welcome  {{ Auth::user()->name }}         else
Welcome please login
endif